# repetitive sending data to django template from view

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views, twitter-streaming-api

I am using twitter streaming api for fetching real time tweets and I want to display the data of tweets as they come. I can't use `HttpResponse()` or `render()` to send data from view to template because it sends data only once. I want to send data repetitively as they come.

now how can I achieve that?

I have few ideas like I can use javascript to refresh page after few seconds but that doesn't seem good idea.

I know it is not good to provide no code but I have not implemented anything regarding that.

views.py

```
class TweetStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def __init__(self,api=None):
        super(TweetStreamListener,self).__init__()
        self.cnt = 1
        self.list = []
        self.end = 5
        print("started")

    def on_status(self, status):
        if self.end >= self.cnt:
            print(status._json['text'])
            self.list.append(status._json['text'])
            self.cnt+=1
        else:
            print('end')
            return False

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print("error", status_code)
        return False

    def on_timeout(self):
        print('timeout')
        return False


def hashtag_details(request):
    streamListener = TweetStreamListener()
    myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth,listener=streamListener)
    hashtag = ((request.path[1:]).split('='))[1]
    myStream.filter(track=hashtag,async=True)
    list = streamListener.list
    template = loader.get_template('list_details.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render({'tweets':list}, request))
```

in list_details.html

```
<script>
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = "redirect_url";
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

is this a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

So, Javascript is totally client-side, meaning that it cannot show you any information that was not provided to it in the initial page load. If you want to live update information to a Django view you have to use something to send that information without the client clicking anything. I believe what you want is JQuery.

Comment: can you explain in brief?